# Change tab bar item badge from other ViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a two tab bar items at the bottom of my application. (Let's call the tab bar items Products & Cart)
On Cart their is a badge item present. How can I change the badge item on Cart while I preform an action on the ViewController of Products.

Steps:
Start -> Cart badge = 0 -> go to Products tab -> add product to cart -> while adding product to cart change Cart badge to 1 -> still on the Products tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming two tabs and cart is second the index of the cart viewcontroller is 1. In you productsview controller you should be able to:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers[1].tabBarItem.badgeValue = "1";
```

I'm not at work and cant test is now. Hope te test it tomorrow.

Comment: it works ( iOS 15.5 )